# Not able to print String on the console

Tags: android, android-volley

I am able to get the JSON Response from the server but it's not printing on the console.

I am using `Volley` library.

```
public class DataFetch {
    public void getSellers(final int pageNumber, final Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String url = BASE_URL + GET_SELLERS_LIST + "?page=" + pageNumber;
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                           System.out.print("*******\n" + response);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Display Error Toast
                Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) {
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(AUTHORIZATION, "Token " + prefs.getString(TOKEN, ""));
                return params;
            }
        };


        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

`response` is available during debugging.

[image: image1]

but it's not getting printed on the console.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
System.out.print("*******\n" + response);
```

With:

```
System.out.println("*******")
System.out.println(response);
```

As far as I know the console cannot print 2 lines in a single print statement.

(If anybody knows better I will happily retract my answer)